# What does happen when we tap on a custom UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drawrect, custom-cell

I have an `UITableView` in my view controller and I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that is used to perform drawing images, drawing text, lines etc..

All these happens within `drawRect:` method. Apart from this, I have seen some methods used along with `drawRect:`

They are..

```
-(void)setNeedsDisplay
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
-(void)layoutSubviews
```

My question is, how/when did we use those methods?

PS: My actual problem is, when I tap on this custom cell, the images and texts that I draw using drawRect: was hidden by the selection background. It is because of the system overrides all the subviews of UITableViewCell with the selection background. But, I want to change only the cell's background color alone when it was tapped.

Just Confused!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to be doing all of the image, text and line drawing in `-drawRect:` (unless you really mean it!). Rather you should put the work of adding subviews into `-layoutSubviews`.

Now, if you all you're doing is customizing the view hierarchy of your custom table cell be sure to add whatever subviews you have to the cell's `contentView`. There are lots of examples out there for how to do this. That *should* handle the layer ordering when you tap the cell and iOS adds the selection view.

As for your other questions you'll probably want to read the docs on `UIView`'s life cycle:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Add your subviews to the cell's `contentView` rather than the cell itself.

Also, you might like `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` to avoid iOS doing any highlighting at all.

If you're subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding its `drawRect:`, that's not going to work. Instead add a child view to the `contentView`, and implement `drawRect` in that child.

Comment: I need to highlight the cell when it was selected. But I don't want to hide my cell contents. Is there any other way?